# Dynamic information in Chrome Extension Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that downloads a file and sends it to a server to analyze that file. Then the server send a response (json) with the results. I would like to show those results on a pop up window and I want to do it in background context. This is what I have:

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); 
    var tittle = "Results of " + data.filename;
    var results = "File " + data.filename +
    " has " + data.similarity + " with " + data.file;

    chrome.windows.create({
      focused: true,
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      type: 'popup',
      url: 'popup2.html',
      top: 0,
      left: 0

    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching JSON: ', error);
      });
  });
```

I have tried with chrome.notifications but it seems not to work in manifest version 3. The only pop up I can show is with chrome.windows.create and its content is predefined obviously. The only information I would like to show is value of variables "tittle" and "results". Does someone have an idea of how I can do it in manifest 3?

Addition:
I have been trying to do it with messages but it is not working:

*background.js*

```js
chrome.windows.create({
  focused: true,
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  type: 'popup',
  url: 'popup2.html',
  top: 0,
  left: 0
},
  (window) => {
    console.log(window.id)

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(window.tabs[0].id, {
      action: 'setData',
      data: data,
    })
  })
```

*popup2.js*

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender) => {
  if (msg.action === 'setData') {
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = JSON.stringify(
      msg.data,
      null,
      '  ');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can store it in chrome.storage or pass via messaging. See also [this answer](/a/54715122).

Comment: I have tried it with messages as I show in EDITION. Would you know why it is still not working?

Comment: The new opened page hasn't yet started when the callback of create() runs so you'll either need a delay or reverse the direction of messaging (the new page sends a message, the original script responds).

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate html dynamically.

```js
const title = "title";
const result = "result";

const html = "<html>" + title +"<br>" + result + "</html>";
const blob = new Blob([html],{type: "text/html"});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

chrome.windows.create({
  focused: true,
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  type: 'popup',
  url: url,
  top: 0,
  left: 0
})
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering but I am getting this error: "TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function"

Comment: Sorry. I tested it with popup. Service worker cannot use `URL.createObjectURL`.

Comment: "I have tried with chrome.notifications but it seems not to work in manifest version 3" - Show us your code and the error message(s).